# Complicated group by - windows

Tags: sql, group-by, window

Can you please help with the following grouping:
Name can have states that can be repeated several times and it is essential in output to have all the state changes over time and to have the starting date of the state

Here is the input data:

```
| name  | state | date
------------------------------
| A     | X     | 01.03.2021
| A     | X     | 02.03.2021
| A     | X     | 03.03.2021
| A     | Y     | 04.03.2021
| A     | Y     | 05.03.2021
| A     | X     | 06.03.2021
| A     | X     | 07.03.2021
| B     | S     | 01.03.2021
| B     | S     | 02.03.2021
| B     | T     | 03.03.2021
| B     | T     | 04.03.2021
| B     | T     | 05.03.2021
| B     | T     | 06.03.2021
| B     | S     | 07.03.2021
```

Desired output

```
| name  | state | date
------------------------------
| A     | X     | 01.03.2021
| A     | Y     | 04.03.2021
| A     | X     | 06.03.2021
| B     | S     | 01.03.2021
| B     | T     | 03.03.2021
| B     | S     | 07.03.2021
```

Comment: Check your DBMS docs. You can use `lag` if it is supported.

Comment: Maybe explain how the output should look like, and show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the start date per consecutive sequence of state per name, this is one solution:

[Test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab23a4e75238efba4430744f8fc551f6)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT name
             , ROW_NUMBER()      OVER (PARTITION BY name        ORDER BY date)
             - ROW_NUMBER()      OVER (PARTITION BY name, state ORDER BY date) AS n
             , state
             , date
          FROM logs
     )
SELECT name
     , MIN(state) AS state
     , MIN(date)  AS min_date
  FROM cte1
 GROUP BY name, n
 ORDER BY name, min_date
;
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+------------+
| name | state | min_date   |
+------+-------+------------+
| A    | X     | 2021-03-01 |
| A    | Y     | 2021-03-04 |
| A    | X     | 2021-03-06 |
| B    | S     | 2021-03-01 |
| B    | T     | 2021-03-03 |
| B    | S     | 2021-03-07 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

The basic form works with most databases, PG, MySQL 8.0, MariaDB 10.2.2+, SQL Server, Oracle (with some adjustments in "date" quoting, type (`VARCHAR2`) and `INSERT` form).

Answer (score 0):

Using LAG to detect the changes. `Date` is a reserved word in many DBMSes, using `dt` instead.

```
SELECT name
     , state
     , dt AS min_date
FROM (
       SELECT *
          , case lag(state) over (partiton by name odrer by dt) when state then 0 else 1 end flag
       FROM logs
     ) t
WHERE flag = 1
ORDER BY name, dt
```